# What will happen if I don't specify a version for a Maven dependency?

Tags: maven

i have seen in the project maven dependency specified like the following,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

there is no version defined in the dependency, so what will happen if i don't give version name and why it is given like above.

would some one explain the reason please.

Comment: Over time, procedures are added and removed, you shouldn't expect a project keeping whatever procedures you're relying forever

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in the ordinary dependency section of your poject. The only case I know that this is allowed is when you inherit a parent project with a [`<dependencyManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section, which is used to coordinate dependency versions across a set of projects. Then you can use the "shorthand" definition, without the version. But it would still have a version, which it inherits from the dependency defined in the parent project.

There are some other places in the pom you can drop the version as well, but those are not directly relevant to including dependencies (like plugins/exludes etc).

Comment: There are at least three ways that this can be set up. One is inheriting dependencymanagement from parent pom, second is using dependencymanagement in the same pom, and third is having a dependency to a pom file with scope:import that has it in the dependencymanagement. Or any combination of these. But you are correct in the basic principle - it has to be defined *somewhere*.

Comment: Maven won't allow any other either. Build will fail if version is not found.

Comment: Sure, dependencyManagement in the same project would work, but then you have the version in the same pom, which I assumed was not the case here. Didn't know about the import though.

Answer (score -1):

I have put the following maven dependency with a version in my pom.xml and it is working fine.

 `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>`